# Sorting by pivot table results

Tags: sql, mysql

I had to create a report for a customer by most sold products in the last month and sorted by parameters they have assigned.

We have three parameters on products: `Colour`, `Type` and `Collection`.

The desired result is to sort products by most sold `Collection`, then most sold `Colour`, then most sold `Type`. The query I have written is monstrous, and I am sure it could be written efficiently.

```
SELECT a.ID, collection.value as title, colour.value as colour, type.value as type
FROM orderrows oa
JOIN order o ON o.ID = oa.orderID
JOIN products a ON oa.productid = a.ID
JOIN productparameter as collection ON collection.productid = a.ID AND collection.parameterid = 'collection_id'
JOIN productparameter as type ON type.productid = a.ID AND type.parameterid = 'type_id'
JOIN productparameter as colour ON colour.productid = a.ID AND colour.parameterid = 'colour_id'
JOIN
(
    SELECT @rowId:=@rowId+1 AS rowId, collection.title
    FROM
    (
        SELECT collection.value as title
        FROM orderrows oa
        JOIN order o ON o.ID = oa.orderID
        JOIN products a ON oa.productid = a.ID
        JOIN productparameter as collection ON collection.productid = a.ID AND collection.parameterid = 'collection_id'
        WHERE o.orderdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        GROUP BY collection.value
        ORDER BY SUM(oa.productprice * oa.productamount) DESC
    ) collection,
    (
        SELECT @rowId:=0
    ) t2
) as collection_sort ON collection.value = collection_sort.title
JOIN
(
    SELECT @rowId:=@rowId+1 AS rowId, colour.title
    FROM
    (
        SELECT colour.value as title
        FROM orderrows oa
        JOIN order o ON o.ID = oa.orderID
        JOIN products a ON oa.productid = a.ID
        JOIN productparameter as colour ON colour.productid = a.ID AND colour.parameterid = 'colour_id'
        WHERE o.orderdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        GROUP BY colour.value
        ORDER BY SUM(oa.productprice * oa.productamount) DESC
    ) colour,
    (
        SELECT @rowId:=0
    ) t2
) as colour_sort ON colour.value = colour_sort.title
JOIN
(
    SELECT @rowId:=@rowId+1 AS rowId, type.title
    FROM
    (
        SELECT type.value as title
        FROM orderrows oa
        JOIN order o ON o.ID = oa.orderID
        JOIN products a ON oa.productid = a.ID
        JOIN productparameter as type ON type.productid = a.ID AND type.parameterid = 'type_id'
        WHERE o.orderdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
        GROUP BY type.value
        ORDER BY SUM(oa.productprice * oa.productamount) DESC
    ) type,
    (
        SELECT @rowId:=0
    ) t2
) as type_sort ON type.value = type_sort.title
WHERE o.orderdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY a.ID
ORDER BY collection_sort.rowId ASC, colour_sort.rowId ASC, type_sort.rowId ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `a` as alias for `products` is not the best choice.
2. You don't use anything from `products` in your subqueries. So you don't need to join it.
3. If you only need the *productID*, you can also skip the `products` table in the outer query and use `oa.productid` instead.
4. You don't need a `rowId` - You can use the `SUM` to order the result.

So you query could look like:

```
SELECT p.ID, collection.value as title, colour.value as colour, type.value as type
FROM orderrows oa
JOIN order o ON o.ID = oa.orderID
JOIN products p ON oa.productid = p.ID
JOIN productparameter as collection ON collection.productid = p.ID AND collection.parameterid = 'collection_id'
JOIN productparameter as type ON type.productid = p.ID AND type.parameterid = 'type_id'
JOIN productparameter as colour ON colour.productid = p.ID AND colour.parameterid = 'colour_id'
JOIN
(
    SELECT collection.value, SUM(oa.productprice * oa.productamount) as total
    FROM orderrows oa
    JOIN order o ON o.ID = oa.orderID
    JOIN productparameter as collection ON collection.productid = oa.productid AND collection.parameterid = 'collection_id'
    WHERE o.orderdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    GROUP BY collection.value
) as collection_sort ON collection.value = collection_sort.value
JOIN
(
    SELECT colour.value, SUM(oa.productprice * oa.productamount) as total
    FROM orderrows oa
    JOIN order o ON o.ID = oa.orderID
    JOIN productparameter as colour ON colour.productid = oa.productid AND colour.parameterid = 'colour_id'
    WHERE o.orderdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    GROUP BY colour.value
) as colour_sort ON colour.value = colour_sort.value
JOIN
(
    SELECT type.value, SUM(oa.productprice * oa.productamount) as total
    FROM orderrows oa
    JOIN order o ON o.ID = oa.orderID
    JOIN productparameter as type ON type.productid = oa.productid AND type.parameterid = 'type_id'
    WHERE o.orderdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    GROUP BY type.value
) as type_sort ON type.value = type_sort.value
WHERE o.orderdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY a.ID
ORDER BY collection_sort.total DESC, colour_sort.total DESC, type_sort.total DESC
```

That are 37 lines of code instead of 64.

But there are still three subqueries which are almost equal. You can merge them to this one:

```
SELECT pp.parameterid, pp.value, SUM(oa.productprice * oa.productamount) as total
FROM orderrows oa
JOIN `order` o ON o.ID = oa.orderID
JOIN productparameter as pp ON pp.productid = oa.productid
WHERE o.orderdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  AND collection.parameterid IN ('collection_id', 'colour_id', 'type_id')
GROUP BY pp.parameterid, pp.value
```

and use conditional aggregation to pivot the result in the outer query:

```
SELECT 
    p.ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.parameterid = 'collection_id' THEN t.value END) as collection,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.parameterid = 'colour_id'     THEN t.value END) as colour,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.parameterid = 'type_id'       THEN t.value END) as `type`
FROM (
    SELECT pp.parameterid, pp.value, SUM(oa.productprice * oa.productamount) as total
    FROM orderrows oa
    JOIN `order` o ON o.ID = oa.orderID
    JOIN productparameter as pp ON pp.productid = oa.productid
    WHERE o.orderdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
      AND collection.parameterid IN ('collection_id', 'colour_id', 'type_id')
    GROUP BY pp.parameterid, pp.value
) t
JOIN productparameter pp ON pp.parameterid = t.parameterid
JOIN products p ON p.ID = pp.productid
JOIN orderrows oa ON oa.productid = p.ID
JOIN `order` o ON o.ID = oa.orderID
WHERE o.orderdate > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.parameterid = 'collection_id' THEN t.total END) DESC,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.parameterid = 'colour_id'     THEN t.total END) DESC,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.parameterid = 'type_id'       THEN t.total END) DESC
```

(24 lines)